# Help with this challenge of the second degree equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Mathematics course, and I love this science, I am very curious, and these days, studying a book of calculus found in (book from the library of the University) a sheet full of challenges, to share with a colleague, he gave me this challenge, which he also failed to respond ...
I tried, I tried, I used the formulas of quadratic equation, and I've been trying since Friday (here in Brazil is Sunday at 22:33), and could not, and I ask your help, and please believe me, I struggled, tried to make substitutions, tried both, and I'm confused ... I must find the values of $ a, b $ and $ c $?

Consider a parabola whose roots, $x'$ and $x''$, are such that $x'=-x''$ where $x'> 0$. 
Define $$A = (x', 0)$$ $$B = (x'', 0)$$ and let $V$ be the vertex of the parabola. If the equation of this parabola is $$y = ax^2 +bx+ c$$ calculate the value of the discriminant $$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$ so that the triangle AVB is equilateral.